# How to select +1 record from MSSQL using EF with single query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

In short:

I have records that have `CreationTime` column in database. I want to select records from last 2 days PLUS one record that follows (sort by creation date desc) that can be any time old.

So from records (knowing that today date is 11th March) I want to select all records that are at max 2 days old + 1:

```
1. 2019-03-11
2. 2019-03-11
3. 2019-03-10
4. 2019-03-08
5. 2019-03-07
6. 2019-03-16
```

So result should contain records 1,2,3,4. (4. even though it is 3 days old, it is that "+1" record I need).

I'm using MSSQL and .NET 4.6.1 Entity Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO cleaner way to achieve this is to write two queries: first to get data from last two days and second is to get the latest record older than 2 days.

To get records from last 2 days:

```
select * from MyTable where CreationTime between getdate() and getdate() - 2
```

To get additional record:

```
select top 1 * from MyTable where CreationTme < getdate() - 2 order by CreationTime desc
```

Using EF with LINQ methods (`dc` is database context):

To get records from last 2 days:

```
dc.Entitites.Where(e => e.CreationTime <= DateTime.Now && e.CreationTime >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2));
```

additional record:

```
dc.Entities.Where(e => e.CreationTime < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2)).OrderByDescending(e => e.CreationTime).First();
```

Comment: First query `CreationTime >= getdate() - 2` will returns `2019-03-16` which is not required.

Comment: I used this but I added Union so that it is just one query executed on SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(StartDate DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @table
VALUES('2019-03-11'),('2019-03-11'),('2019-03-10'),
      ('2019-03-08'),('2019-03-07'),('2019-03-16')

SELECT * FROM @table WHERE StartDate BETWEEN GETDATE()-4 AND GETDATE()
```

For getting old 4th entry,

```
SELECT * FROM @table
 ORDER BY (select null)
OFFSET (select Count(*) from @table where  StartDate BETWEEN GETDATE()-2 AND 
        GETDATE()) ROWS
 FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: That 4th entry can be any time old.

Comment: You mean  that 4th entry may like '2018-03-05'.right?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Logic

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    SeqNo INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    MyDate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO  @T
VALUES(GETDATE())
,(DATEADD(MINUTE,-23,GETDATE()))
,(DATEADD(MINUTE,-78,GETDATE()))
,(DATEADD(MINUTE,-5443,GETDATE()))
,(DATEADD(MINUTE,-34,GETDATE()))
,(DATEADD(MINUTE,-360,GETDATE()))
,(DATEADD(MINUTE,-900,GETDATE()))
,(DATEADD(MINUTE,-1240,GETDATE()))
,(DATEADD(MINUTE,-3600,GETDATE()))

;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(MyDate AS DATE) ORDER BY MyDate DESC),
        DateSeq = DATEDIFF(DAY,MyDate,GETDATE()),
        *
        FROM @T
)
SELECT
    *
    FROM CTE
        WHERE 
            DateSeq <2
            OR
            (
                DateSeq = 2
                AND 
                RN = 1
            )
```